ORM Mapping different type of users
I have an app with different types of users. All type of users share common properties like username, firstname and lastname. The different type of users are:

Child
Guardian
Teacher

Teacher has all the properties of user, but also an email and phone number. Idem for child and guardian, but there is a many-to-many relationship between these two entities. A child can have multiple parents, and a parent can have multiple children.
I designed my models to have a parent-class User with the common properties, and I have a class for each type as subclass. The idea was that it'd generate database tables Users, Children, Guardians, and Teachers. Where the last three would have a FK to Users so when I retrieve e.g a Teacher I can also retrieve it's first- and lastname.
These are my models:
User.php
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use App\Domain\Model\Timestampable;
use App\Domain\Model\HasUuid;

class User
{
    use Timestampable;
    use HasUuid;

    public function __construct(
        private string $username,
        private string $firstName,
        private string $lastName,
        private string $passcode,
    )
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->passcode = $passcode;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): void
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): void
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName(): string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): void
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getFullName(): string
    {
        return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getPasscode(): string
    {
        return $this->passcode;
    }

    public function setPasscode(string $passcode): void
    {
        $this->passcode = $passcode;
    }
}


Child.php
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use App\Domain\Model\HasUuid;
use App\Domain\Model\User\User;
use App\Domain\Model\User\Guardian;

class Child extends User
{
    use HasUuid;

    public function __construct(
        private string $username,
        private string $firstName,
        private string $lastName,
        private string $passcode,
        private array $guardians,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($username, $firstName, $lastName, $passcode);
    }

    public function getGuardians(): array
    {
        return $this->guardians;
    }

    public function addGuardian(Guardian $guardian): void
    {
        $this->guardians[] = $guardian;
    }
}


Guardian.php
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use App\Domain\Model\HasUuid;
use App\Domain\Model\User\User;
use App\Domain\Model\User\Child;

class Guardian extends User
{
    use HasUuid;

    public function __construct(
        private string $username,
        private string $firstName,
        private string $lastName,
        private string $passcode,
        private string $email,
        private string $telnr,
        private array $children,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($username, $firstName, $lastName, $passcode);
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getTelnr(): string
    {
        return $this->telnr;
    }

    public function setTelnr(string $telnr): void
    {
        $this->telnr = $telnr;
    }

    public function getChildren(): array
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function addChild(Child $child): void
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }
}

Teacher.php
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Model\User;

use App\Domain\Model\Timestampable;
use App\Domain\Model\HasUuid;
use App\Domain\Model\User\User;

class Teacher extends User
{
    use HasUuid;

    public function __construct(
        private string $username,
        private string $firstName,
        private string $lastName,
        private string $passcode,
        private string $email,
        private string $telnr,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($username, $firstName, $lastName, $passcode);
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->telnr = $telnr;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getTelnr(): string
    {
        return $this->telnr;
    }

    public function setTelnr(string $telnr): void
    {
        $this->telnr = $telnr;
    }
}

Now I am using Doctrine/ORM in XML format to generate the database scheme. This is my current config:
User.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="App\Domain\Model\User\User" table="users" inheritance-type="JOINED">
        <id name="id" type="guid" column="id">
            <generator strategy="NONE"/>
        </id>

        <field name="username" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="firstName" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="lastName" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="passcode" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        
        <field name="createdAt" type="datetime" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="updatedAt" type="datetime" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="deletedAt" type="datetime" nullable="true"/>
        
        <discriminator-column name="type" type="string" />
        <discriminator-map>
        <discriminator-mapping value="teacher" class="App\Domain\Model\User\Teacher" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="guardian" class="App\Domain\Model\User\Guardian" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="child" class="App\Domain\Model\User\Child" />
    </discriminator-map>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

Child.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="App\Domain\Model\User\Child" table="children">

        <!-- Many-to-many relationship with Guardian -->
        <many-to-many field="guardians" target-entity="App\Domain\Model\User\Guardian">
            <join-table name="guardians_children">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="child_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="guardian_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/> <!-- Ensure NOT NULL -->
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
        </many-to-many>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

Guardian.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="App\Domain\Model\User\Guardian" table="guardians">

        <!-- Many-to-many relationship with Child -->
        <many-to-many field="children" target-entity="App\Domain\Model\User\Child" inversed-by="guardians">
            <join-table name="guardian_child">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="guardian_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/> <!-- Ensure NOT NULL -->
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="child_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/> <!-- Ensure NOT NULL -->
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
        </many-to-many>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

Teacher.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="App\Domain\Model\User\Teacher" table="teachers">
        <field name="email" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="telnr" type="string" length="50" nullable="false"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

Generating a migration from this creates the following tables:
[
As you can see the tables contain the correct fields and user contains a discriminator to determine the type of user. But the tables representing the different types of users are missing something. When I would retrieve a teacher in this database I would have no idea what user it actually is and it would be impossible to get the firstname, lastname,... because the table Teachers does not have a FK to the table Users.
I thought I could solve this by adding a many-to-one in the sub-tables in xml:
    <entity name="App\Domain\Model\User\Teacher" table="teachers">
        <field name="email" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="telnr" type="string" length="50" nullable="false"/>
        
        <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="App\Domain\Model\User\User" inversed-by="teachers">
            <join-column name="id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </entity>

But this gives the following error:
 Property App\Domain\Model\User\Teacher::$user does not exist

This could be solved by adding a property $user to the Teacher-class. But Teacher is already extending from User so that does not really seem to make sense to me.
I think I am doing something wrong, how do I successfully implement different type of users?

Now I am using Doctrine/ORM in XML side question - why makelife harder for no real benefit? Why not just use PHP attributes for your entity class' properties to set thst up?

Also, do not post images of text (table schema). Post just text

@MarcinOrlowski Because I am using a hexagonal architecture. I want to decouple my Modals from the database/persistence layer.

Have a look at inheritance https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.3/reference/inheritance-mapping.html
It takes care of FKs and relations for you
